# java Android sort ArrayList<float[]>

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, arraylist

how can a ArrayList be sorted acording to the first dimension of each item in the array?

example:

[image: ArrayList<float[]> to be sorted]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a custom comparator. For instance:

```
Comparator<float[]> byFirstElement = new Comparator<float[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(float[] arg0, float[] arg1) {
        return Float.compare(arg0[0], arg1[0]);
    }
};
Collections.sort(theArray, byFirstElement);
```

This implementation assumes that both `float[]` arrays actually have at least one element; if they don't, the comparison will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. If you're not absolutely sure that the arrays will always be non-empty, your `compare` function should check `arg0.length` and `arg1.length`, and handle them appropriately (the three cases you need to handle are when only `arg0` is empty, when only `arg1` is empty, or when both are empty).

It's a good idea to assign that `Comparator<float[]>` to a `private static final` in your class. That's a tad more efficient, since you don't need to create a new object each time you use it; but far more importantly, it gives it a nice, easy-to-read name.

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(floatArray2, new Comparator() { 

    public int compare(float[] arg0, float[] arg1) {
        return arg0[0] == arg1[0] ? 0 : arg0[0] < arg1[0] ? -1 : 1;
    } 
});
```